# SQLite3: Return a NULL if no records exist in SUM()

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to `SUM()` while also using a `WHERE` but when there are no records found for a certain `ID` I would like it to return `NULL` instead of just not returning anything.

Initial Code:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EVENTS = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Events_ID
WHERE
    YEAR = 2012
GROUP BY ID
```

This would not return an `ID` if there were no events for it in 2012.

I then changed it to the following that appears to work but is around 100x slower!

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    (SELECT 
         SUM(CASE WHEN EVENTS = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     FROM EVENTS_ID r WHERE r.ID = t.ID AND r.YEAR = 2012) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM Events_ID GROUP BY ID) as t;
```

Is there anyway to get the output of the second query nearer to the speed of the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EVENTS = 3 AND YEAR = 2012 THEN 1 END)
FROM Events_ID
GROUP BY ID;
```

This will return all ids, with a `NULL` as a second value if no events match both conditions.